# Locales Ruby on Rails issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a issue with Locales.  In rails app /config/locales/ I have two files: cs.rb & en.yml.  At the end, the output of price is in $. Why is this?

my index.html.erb looks

```
<% if notice %>
<p id="notice" ><%= notice %></p>
<% end %> 

<h1>Zoznam produktov</h1>

<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <div class="entry" >
    <%= image_tag(product.image_url) %>
    <h3><%= product.title %></h3>
    <%= sanitize(product.description) %>
    <div class="price_line" > 
      <span class="price">
        <%= number_to_currency(product.price, :locale => :cs) %>
 %>
      </span>       
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

@Зелёный

First is cs.rb and second is en.yml

```
# Czech translations for Ruby on Rails
# by Karel Minařík (karmi@karmi.cz)
# contributors:
#  - Vít Krchov - http://github.com/vita - Rails 3 update

unless defined?(CzechLocaleI18n::ERROR_MESSAGES)
  module CzechLocaleI18n
    ERROR_MESSAGES = {
      :inclusion           => "není v seznamu povolených hodnot",
      :exclusion           => "je vyhrazeno pro jiný účel",
      :invalid             => "není platná hodnota",
      :confirmation        => "nebylo potvrzeno",
      :accepted            => "musí být potvrzeno",
      :empty               => "nesmí být prázdný/á/é",
      :blank               => "je povinná položka", # alternate formulation: "is required"
      :too_long            => "je příliš dlouhý/á/é (max. %{count} znaků)",
      :too_short           => "je příliš krátký/á/é (min. %{count} znaků)",
      :wrong_length        => "nemá správnou délku (očekáváno %{count} znaků)",
      :not_a_number        => "není číslo",
      :greater_than        => "musí být větší než %{count}",
      :greater_than_or_equal_to => "musí být větší nebo rovno %{count}",
      :equal_to            => "musí být rovno %{count}",
      :less_than           => "musí být méně než %{count}",
      :less_than_or_equal_to    => "musí být méně nebo rovno %{count}",
      :odd                 => "musí být liché číslo",
      :even                => "musí být sudé číslo",
      :not_an_integer       => "musí být celé číslo"
    }
  end
end

{ :'cs' => {

    # ActiveSupport
    :support => {
      :array => {
    :two_words_connector => ' a ',
    :last_word_connector => ' a ',
    :words_connector => ', '
      },
      :select => {
    :prompt => 'Prosím vyberte si',
      }
    },

    # Date
    :date => {
      :formats => {
    :default => "%d. %m. %Y",
    :short   => "%d %b",
    :long    => "%d. %B %Y",
      },
      :day_names         => %w{Neděle Pondělí Úterý Středa Čtvrtek Pátek Sobota},
      :abbr_day_names    => %w{Ne Po Út St Čt Pá So},
      :month_names       => %w{~ Leden Únor Březen Duben Květen Červen Červenec Srpen Září Říjen Listopad Prosinec},
      :abbr_month_names  => %w{~ Led Úno Bře Dub Kvě Čvn Čvc Srp Zář Říj Lis Pro},
      :order             => [:day, :month, :year]
    },

    # Time
    :time => {
      :formats => {
    :default => "%a %d. %B %Y %H:%M %z",
    :short   => "%d. %m. %H:%M",
    :long    => "%A %d. %B %Y %H:%M",
      },
      :am => 'am',
      :pm => 'pm'
    },

    # Numbers
    :number => {
      :format => {
    :precision => 3,
    :separator => '.',
    :delimiter => ',',
    :significant => false,
    :strip_insignificant_zeros => false
      },
      :currency => {
    :format => {
      :unit => 'Kč',
      :precision => 2,
      :format    => '%n %u',
      :separator => ",",
      :delimiter => " ",
      :significant => false,
      :strip_insignificant_zeros => false
    }
      },
      :human => {
    :format => {
      :precision => 1,
      :delimiter => '',
      :significant => false,
      :strip_insignificant_zeros => false
    },
       :storage_units => {
     :format => "%n %u",
     :units => {
       :byte => "B",
       :kb   => "KB",
       :mb   => "MB",
       :gb   => "GB",
       :tb   => "TB",
     }
       },
       :decimal_units => {
     :format => "%n %u",
     :units => {
       :unit => "",
       :thousand => "Tisíc",
       :million => "Milion",
       :billion => "Miliarda",
       :trillion => "Bilion",
       :quadrillion => "Kvadrilion"
     }
       }
      },
      :percentage => {
    :format => {
      :delimiter => ''
    }
      },
      :precision => {
    :format => {
      :delimiter => ''
    }
      }
    },

    # Distance of time ... helper
    # NOTE: In Czech language, these values are different for the past and for the future. Preference has been given to past here.
    :datetime => {
      :prompts => {
    :second => "Sekunda",
    :minute => "Minuta",
    :hour => "Hodina",
    :day => "Den",
    :month => "Měsíc",
    :year => "Rok"
      },
      :distance_in_words => {
    :half_a_minute => 'půl minutou',
    :less_than_x_seconds => {
      :one => 'necelou sekundou',
      :other => 'ani ne %{count} sekundami'
    },
    :x_seconds => {
      :one => 'sekundou',
      :other => '%{count} sekundami'
    },
    :less_than_x_minutes => {
      :one => 'necelou minutou',
      :other => 'ani ne %{count} minutami'
    },
    :x_minutes => {
      :one => 'minutou',
      :other => '%{count} minutami'
    },
    :about_x_hours => {
      :one => 'asi hodinou',
      :other => 'asi %{count} hodinami'
    },
    :x_days => {
      :one => '24 hodinami',
      :other => '%{count} dny'
    },
    :about_x_months => {
      :one => 'asi měsícem',
      :other => 'asi %{count} měsíci'
    },
    :x_months => {
      :one => 'měsícem',
      :other => '%{count} měsíci'
    },
    :about_x_years => {
      :one => 'asi rokem',
      :other => 'asi %{count} roky'
    },
    :over_x_years => {
      :one => 'více než rokem',
      :other => 'více než %{count} roky'
    },
    :almost_x_years => {
      :one => 'téměř rokem',
      :other => 'téměř %{count} roky'
    }
      }
    },

    :helpers => {
      :select => {
    :prompt => "Prosím vyberte si"
      },

      :submit => {
    :create => "Vytvořit %{model}",
    :update => "Aktualizovat %{model}",
    :submit => "Uložit %{model}"
      }
    },

    :errors => {
      :format => "%{attribute} %{message}",
      :messages => CzechLocaleI18n::ERROR_MESSAGES
    },

    # ActiveRecord validation messages
    :activerecord => {
      :errors => {
    :messages => {
      :taken               => "již databáze obsahuje",
      :record_invalid      => "Validace je neúspešná: %{errors}"
    }.merge(CzechLocaleI18n::ERROR_MESSAGES),
    :template => {
      :header   => {
        :one => "Při ukládání objektu %{model} došlo k chybám a nebylo jej možné uložit",
        :other => "Při ukládání objektu %{model} došlo ke %{count} chybám a nebylo možné jej uložit"
      },
      :body  => "Následující pole obsahují chybně vyplněné údaje:"
    },
    :full_messages => {
      :format => "%{attribute} %{message}"
    }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#

```
# Sample localization file for English. Add more files in   this      directory for other locales.
# See http://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails%2Flocale for starting points.
en:
  hello: "Hello world"
```

Comment: Do you have the locale file in your /locales folder?

Comment: Please include related locales(en, cs) and error.

Comment: `I have two files: cs.rb & en.yml` why it is `cs.rb`??

Comment: @SimoneCarletti No i haven't. I my locales folder I have just this two files.

Comment: @mudasobwa cs.rb is czech language

Comment: @Зелёный Sorry, I don't understand your idea

Comment: _I my locales folder I have just this two files_ - show us it please.

Comment: `number_to_currency` method is what should be posted as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have not defined cs.yml in locale directory that's why, it is taking default as en locale.

please define cs.yml instead of cs.rb

Comment: Rails allow `*.rb` [setup-the-rails-application-for-internationalization](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/i18n.html#configure-the-i18n-module)

Comment: @dipak gupta 
please check my cs.rb above. Could I just retype .cs to .yml? Make the author of this cs.rb mistake?

Answer (score 0):

For this to work you need to have a locale file at config/locales/fr.yml for this to work.

The :locale option only declares to Rails what locale you want it to be. Rails does not have all the translations for every language in the project, and so you must include these translation files yourself.